# "Identifier expected" error—can not find the source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm stuck with this "Identifier expected" error and I can not find what I'm missing. Code below produces the error. If I comment out the method I'm defining, the error goes away. Seems like it should be a simple syntax issue from other posts, but I can not find what I've done wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class statsMagic : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int value;
    public List<int> mixingTable = new List<int>();
    
    public void addValue(value)
    {
        mixingTable.Add(value);
    }

}
```

I really appreciate if anyone can see what I'm missing.

Comment: `public void addValue(int value)`. But `value` is a keyword, so putting `@value` wherever you use `value` is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'll change now. Adding the int help! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the type of the parameter that is required by your `addValue` method:

```
public void addValue(int value) // note the int
{
    mixingTable.Add(value);
}
```